# Return to old behavior for Perl hash randomization

Tags: perl

I am trying to upgrade Perl from version 5.16 to 5.26 and hashes are randomized differently now. Is there a way to return to the old behavior of 5.16? I have an issue with the new behavior, because the existing code and tests depend on the old predictable hash order.

Comment: The old hash behaviour was NOT predictable.  Any time the hash grows, there's a chance of getting the current behaviour even in 5.16. Sort the keys if you want a consistent order.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implementation of hashes was seriously reworked in 5.18, see this [in perl5180delta](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta#Hash-overhaul).

It's not stated in the (original form of the ) question which part of the extensive overhaul is the problem but it seems that the [PERL_PERTURB_KEYS environment variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta#PERL_PERTURB_KEYS-environment-variable-added) can help

> The `PERL_PERTURB_KEYS` environment variable allows one to control the level of randomization applied to `keys` and friends.
>
> When `PERL_PERTURB_KEYS` is 0, perl will not randomize the key order at all. The chance that `keys` changes due to an insert will be the same as in previous perls, basically only when the bucket size is changed.
> ...

A fuller discussion can be found [in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#PERL_HASH_SEED), for `PERL_HASH_SEED`

> ...
> If the option is provided, and `PERL_PERTURB_KEYS` is NOT set, then a value of '0' implies `PERL_PERTURB_KEYS=0`/`PERL_PERTURB_KEYS=NO` and any other value implies `PERL_PERTURB_KEYS=2`/`PERL_PERTURB_KEYS=DETERMINISTIC`. See the documentation for `PERL_PERTURB_KEYS` for important caveats regarding the `DETERMINISTIC` mode.
> ...

and in the immediately following [PERL_PERTURB_KEYS](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#PERL_PERTURB_KEYS) (my emphasis)

> ...
> (Since Perl 5.18.0) Set to "`0`" or "`NO`" then traversing keys will be repeatable from run to run for the same `PERL_HASH_SEED`. Insertion into a hash will not change the order, except to provide for more space in the hash.  **When combined with setting `PERL_HASH_SEED` this mode is as close to pre 5.18 behavior as you can get.**
> ...

So set these environment variables, or set `PERL_HASH_SEED` and the other one will be set accordingly, for repeated runs of the program to have the same ordering etc.  (Note that if keys are added to a hash then it may get randomized in pre-5.18 code as well, in which case setting these variables in 5.18+ won't help. A safer way is to always sort keys.)

I understand the argument for reverting to the old behavior but I have to suggest to read the full documentation and consider security implications.

Also see [Algorithmic Complexity Attacks in perlsec](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks).

---

The environment variables for this need be set in the shell, for example in bash as

```
export PERL_HASH_SEED=0
```

This can be done in the terminal in which the program will be run, or in `.bashrc` so you don't have to do it every time when opening a terminal.  (But then it affects all scripts run from that shell.) Or, can do it on the same command-line where the program is started

```
$ PERL_HASH_SEED=0 program.pl arguments
```

If the progam is started by another program (not directly in a shell), then you can also set it via the [`%ENV` hash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#%25ENV) in the parent since the environment is inherited by child processes. Then one self-contained way to organize all this is to add a short wrapper script, with

```
$ENV{PERL_HASH_SEED} = 0;

my @cmd = ...

system( @cmd ) == 0 or ...
```

Of course there are a number of ways to run a command out of a Perl program other than [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system), starting with builtin [qx](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#qx/STRING/) (operator form of "backticks") and [pipe-open](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut#Opening-Pipes) (also see this [in perlipc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc#Using-open()-for-IPC)), which allow some control over command's output.  Or, better yet, use libraries like `IPC::System::Simple`, `Capture::Tiny`, `IPC::Run` (from simpler to more powerful).

Comment: @TzachOren  Added a suggestion to perhaps write a wrapper, to the end.  Also added another comment -- a  hash may get randomized if keys are added even in pre-5.18 perls

Answer (score 7):

The  documentation for the change to hash randomization lives [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta#Hash-randomization)

Below is the setting that will get you a consistent order

> Setting PERL_HASH_SEED=0 (exactly one 0) implies PERL_PERTURB_KEYS=0
> (hash key randomization disabled)

You can get the keys to return in a consistent order which I suspect isn't enough for your purposes.

Let's test with a small script anyway

```
# create a hash
my %hash = map { $_ => $_ } 'a' .. 'e';

printHashKeys(\%hash);
printHashKeys(\%hash);
printHashKeys(\%hash);
printHashKeys(\%hash);


sub printHashKeys
{
    my $h = shift ;
    my %hash = %$h;

    for my $key (keys %hash)
    {
        print "$key  " ;
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Running with Perl 5.30.2, I get this - keys order is different each time.

```
$ perl try.pl 
c  a  e  b  d  
a  c  e  b  d  
d  b  e  a  c  
a  c  e  b  d
```

Now with `PERL_HASH_SEED` set to 0. This time they keys come out in a consistent order

```
$ PERL_HASH_SEED=0 perl try.pl 
b  c  d  e  a  
b  c  d  e  a  
b  c  d  e  a  
b  c  d  e  a
```